# Laravel Eloquent Sum Column Between Two Dates for Given Interval

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a bookings table that has a `check_in` and `check_out` columns in addition to deposit and balance columns. The `check_in` and `check_out` are date columns while deposit and balance is decimal column.

I want to generate a report for revenue that sums the deposit and balance columns for a given date interval (supplied from the UI). Here is what I have:

```php
$deposit = Booking::whereRaw("check_in >=  '$start'")
    ->whereRaw("check_out <=  '$end'")
    ->sum('deposit');

$balance = Booking::whereRaw("check_in >=  '$start'")
    ->whereRaw("check_out <=  '$end'")
    ->sum('balance');

$revenue = $deposit + $balance;
```

I am however getting wrong figures. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are getting wrong figures, we cannot know why. But I would say, why are you using `whereRaw` instead of just `where('check_in', '>=', $start)`? Still, wec annot know what is "wrong" as you are not saying what would be the expected output and what is the actual result

Answer (score 0):

When you chain `whereRaw` you get the result for the records that have both, as AND. Maybe you want OR

Let's say we have this table

[image]

`DB::table('checkout')->whereRaw("check_in >= 5")->whereRaw("check_out < 5")->sum("sum")` gets you the result 0, since none of the records have check_out < 5 and check_in >= 5 at the same time.

`DB::table('checkout')->whereRaw("check_in >= 5 OR check_out < 5")->sum("sum")` gets you 10.

This should point you in the right way.